# configure my router to translate "example.com" to a website's IP

Tags: router, dns, dnsmasq

Is possible to confingure my router to translate certain domain names ex:"`example.com`"
to a specified website's IP ex:"`173.194.32.23`" ???

I have a Sitecom Modem Router N300, and there are a lot of settings, but I don't understand what I have to configure.. DNS server, DNSmasq, virtual server...??

Comment: This is what always happens; it just happens in the background. You want to view the IP address in the browser?

Comment: i would like to add my custom word to translate

Answer (score 1):

This can be done on individual computers by modifying a plain text file called hosts (the file itself usually has plenty of instructions on how to do so). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_file. I really recommend this solution if you have access to all the computers on the network. Note that this will persist across all networks though, since the data is stored on the computer.

A quick look at the [manual for your router](http://www.sitecom.com/file/wlr-4003-full-manual/pdf/13072) shows that the exact feature you're looking for is not possible. However, I noticed a Virtual Server function that could (possibly) be used for your problem. You can forward port 80 inside your LAN to a computer that needs to act as a DNS server, it's very complicated, and I'm not even sure that's feasible.

Another solution would be to just create a subdomain on a site you own and have that correspond to the IP you want (if the IP is local, you can't do that).

If what you're looking for is just URL blocking, your router supports that (under Firewall settings).